# How can I remove an existing Gradient Mesh from an object in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, gradient-mesh

I just messed up using the Gradient Mesh Tool in Adobe Illustrator.

I want to start a brand new Gradient Mesh on the object I messed up on and don't want to delete the original shape.

**How can I remove the existing Gradient Mesh so that I can start a new one from scratch?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no effective way to simply remove a Gradient Mesh from an existing object.

So, instead you need to regenerate an object which matches the original shape but without the mesh applied.

1. Select the Gradient Mesh object
2. choose `Object > Path > Offset Path`
3. enter a value of **zero** in the **Offset** field
4. click OK

This will create a **new object which matches the shape of your original object**. You can then simply delete the original Gradient Mesh object and start over on the new shape.

Comment: And the down vote because???? Please if you have a better answer, by all means post it.

Comment: This created a new object with the existing gradient already applied. Did you miss a step?

Comment: @bynary There is a difference between a  standard **gradient fill** and a **Gradient Mesh**. Yes, with a **gradient fill** a new object is created, matching the shape, with the same gradient fill. However, for a **Gradient Mesh** a new object is created, matching the shape, but *without* any fill. Did you not read the question? `:)` If you need to duplicate a shape with a  standard gradient fill.. just duplicate it and remove the fill. - note -- this is a **2013** question/answer -- Illustrator's new gradient formats (freeform, point, etc) may need other methods.

Comment: Obviously I didn't read it all the way through. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you select the gradient mesh tool then hold alt/option and click the point where you inserted the mesh, it removes it.

Comment: This will indeed remove a *mesh point* .... but it will *not* convert the entire mesh object shape back to a standard shape... it will remain a mesh object (check the Appearance Panel).